# making images links not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my images a link but it is not working as the #flare div is conflicting with the rest of the layout could anyone tell me how to fix this?

I want the "flare set how it is at www.industrygaming.co.uk/newindex.php

please help. :)

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<br /><br />
<div id="flare"></div>
<table class="default" style="width: 1000px" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td class="content" width="33%"><a href="joingosts.php"><img src="NewImages/Home/Ghosts.png" height="190px" height="190px" border="0"></a></td>
    <td class="content" width="33%"><img src="NewImages/Home/Clan.png" width="200px" height="80px"></td>
    <td class="content" width="33%"><img src="NewImages/Home/Fifa.png" width="200px" height="200px"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content
{
float: left;
width: 998px;
margin: 0;
color: #fff;
font-size: 17px;
font-family: Times, serif;
min-height: 150px;
}

#flare
{
position: absolute;
display: block;
background-image: url("NewImages/Home/Optical-Flare.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:990px 700px;
min-width: 998px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: -155px;
min-height: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Is it not necessary to close img tag ?

Comment: @vaibhavshah no it is not necessary. `<img src="url">` is proper syntax.

Comment: Hi , make the flare div relative so it can come over the images and look like the website you have pointed to , for the images to be clickable make the pointer-events:none ; for the flare div . Please create a fiddle if you want to see it in action .

Comment: are you sure to follow the w3c determination. Here is the link http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: soon as i added what you said it messes up my layout, never made a fiddle before. :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your design, but it is happening due to "`position:absolute`" to "`div#flare.`"
So just put below code in your css and it will work. Then modify it as per your requirement.

```
table.default{position: absolute; top: 550px}
```